# Create custom name for string array elements in SOAP request body

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

I am writing a small SOAP webservice (for pleasure, not gain) and I am stuck with a little problem that is bugging me - even though it is not a major one.

I have the following method:

```
public class GetCustomerByCodeRequest
{
    public string Code;
}

public class GetCustomerByCodeResponse
{
    public Customer GetCustomerResult;
    public string Status;
    public string StatusDetail;
}

[WebMethod]
[SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
[return: XmlElement("GetCustomerResponse")]
public GetCustomerResponse GetCustomer(GetCustomerRequest GetCustomer)
{
    return null;
}
```

When I look at the SOAP Request format it looks perfect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCustomerByCode xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Code>string</Code>
    </GetCustomerByCode>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The Code is passed as a single element - just what I intend.  However, for my function that returns multiple customers when multiple codes are entered I have a problem:

```
public class GetCustomersByCodeRequest
{
    public string[] Codes;
}

public class GetCustomersByCodeResponse
{
    public Customer[] GetCustomersResult;
    public string Status;
    public string StatusDetail;
}

[WebMethod]
[SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
[return: XmlElement("GetCustomersByCodeResponse")]
public GetCustomersByCodeResponse GetCustomersByCode(GetCustomersByCodeRequest GetCustomersByCode)
{
    return null;
}
```

When I look at the SOAP request format I see the below:

```
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCustomersByCode xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Codes>
        <string>string</string>
        <string>string</string>
      </Codes>
    </GetCustomersByCode>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What is annoying me is the section when the Codes are defined - I don't want the element names to be 'string'.  I can see why it is doing it - my string array - but I would rather they looked something like the below:

```
<Codes>
  <code>string</code>
  <code>string</code>
</Codes>
```

Is this possible?  I'm very rusty and have tried all sorts but usually end up making it look even worse - with all sorts of nested nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

You want the XmlArrayItem(ElementName = '') attribute. It will transform the default use of the type name in arrays into whatever you want.

```
public class GetCustomersByCodeRequest
{
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName= "Code")]        
    public string[] Codes;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect!  Thank you so much.